# Creat and push value in multidimensional array using php

Tags: php

I have two separate array. Now I want to create multidimensional array using existing two array.
This is my two separate array -

```
Array
(
[0] => 11
[1] => 22
[2] => 33
[3] => 44
)

-------------------
    Array
(
[0] => 555
[1] => 666
[2] => 777
[3] => 888
)
```

I want result in multidimensional array, that is   -

```
Array
(



[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11
        [demoid] => 11
        [1] => 555
        [demovalue] => 555
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 22
        [demoid] => 22
        [1] => 666
        [demovalue] => 666
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 33
        [demoid] => 33
        [1] => 777
        [demovalue] => 777
    )
)
```

Comment: Do you have some code actually attempting to combine them? You should at least try

Comment: Why do you need both numeric and named keys for each value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop around and add the values into a new array - I don't see why you would struggle to do so...

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $val) {
    $new_array[] = array(   0 => $val,
                            'demoid' => $val,
                            1 => $array2[$key],
                            'demovalue' => $array2[$key]);
}
```